# Rotational kinematic finding torque direction (homework)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, torque

[image]

a bicycle wheel attached to an axis that is attached to the rope at the other end and hanging as in the picture.spin the wheel and release the wheel resulted in an angular momentum L that has a direction as in the picture. find the direction of torque that acted with bicycle wheel around point O.

the answer I got is vector A because of gravity but the mg of the wheel would pass through center of mass of the wheel making torque =Fr while r is 0 so im a bit confused about this

Comment: HINT:r is not zero about point O.Gravity force is downwards and you have to take the perpendicular distance from the point O to the line of Force.

Comment: $\tau = r \times F$.

Comment: @RishabhJain, who was your physics teacher in high school?

Comment: @DavidWhite why are you so interested?

Comment: @RishabhJain, because, if you graduated from Dawson High School a few years ago, we have already met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Torque is a vector. It is very different from the force vector (which is what A is) - and has to be at right angles to both the force, and the line that connects the point where the force acts to the pivot (here I believe the pivot is at O). That means it's either B or C; now you need to apply the rule that gives you the correct sign to get the answer. I use the corkscrew rule: if I rotate a corkscrew in the direction that the torque wants to turn my system, then in what direction would the corkscrew move (into the bottle, or out of it?).